# copy values of a column into another column based on a condition using a loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I need to create a complicated "for" loop, but after reading some examples I'm still clueless of how to write it in a proper R way and therefore I'm not sure whether it will work or not. I'm still an R beginner :(

I have a dataset in the long format, with different occasions, however, some occasions are not truly new ones since the date of start is the same, but have a different offence that I need to copy in a new column called "offence2", after this I need to drop the false new occasion, in order to keep only rows that represent new occasions. My real data have up to 8 different offences for a single date, but I made a simpler example.

This are an example of how my data looks like

```
    id<-c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5)
    dstart<-c("25/11/2006", "13/12/2006","13/12/2006","07/02/2006","07/02/2006",
     "15/01/2006", "22/03/2006","18/09/2006", "04/03/2006","04/03/2006",
     "22/08/2006","22/08/2006","11/04/2006", "11/04/2006", "19/10/2006") 
    dstart1<-as.Date(dstart, "%d/%m/%Y")

    offence<-c("a","b","c","b","d","a","a","e","b","a","c","a","a","b","a")
    cod_offence<-c(25, 26,27,26,28,25,25,29,26,25,27,25,25,26,25)

    mydata<-data.frame(id, dstart1, offence, cod_offence)
```

Data

```
       id    dstart1   offence  cod_offence
   1   1   2006-11-25       a          25
   2   1   2006-12-13       b          26
   3   1   2006-12-13       c          27
   4   2   2006-02-07       b          26
   5   2   2006-02-07       d          28
   6   3   2006-01-15       a          25
   7   3   2006-03-22       a          25
   8   3   2006-09-18       e          29
   9   4   2006-03-04       b          26
   10  4   2006-03-04       a          25
   11  4   2006-08-22       c          27
   12  4   2006-08-22       a          25
   13  5   2006-04-11       a          25
   14  5   2006-04-11       b          26
   15  5   2006-10-19       a          25
```

I need something like this:

```
      id    dstart1   offence  cod_offence   offence2
   1   1   2006-11-25       a          25       NA
   2   1   2006-12-13       b          26       c
   3   1   2006-12-13       c          27       NA
   4   2   2006-02-07       b          26       d
   5   2   2006-02-07       d          28       NA
   6   3   2006-01-15       a          25       NA
   7   3   2006-03-22       a          25       NA
   8   3   2006-09-18       e          29       NA
   9   4   2006-03-04       b          26       a
   10  4   2006-03-04       a          25       NA
   11  4   2006-08-22       c          27       a
   12  4   2006-08-22       a          25       NA
   13  5   2006-04-11       a          25       b
   14  5   2006-04-11       b          26       NA
   15  5   2006-10-19       a          25       NA
```

I think that I need to do something like this:
given i=individual
      j=observation within individual

```
for each individual I need to check whether mydata$dstart1(j) = mydata$dstart1(j+1)
if this is true, then copy mydata$offence2(j)=mydata$offence(j+1), otherwise keep the same value
This has to stop if id(j) != id(j+1) and re-start with the new id.
```

My problem is that I don't know how to put this in a loop.

Thank you!!

Update

Yes, it'w works fine with the example, but not yet with my real data, since they are a little bit more complex
What happen if instead of two repeated dates I have three or more? each one of them with different offences. Following @CathG solution, I need to create more variables according to the number of offences (in my case 8), I guess I would need a new vector that identify the position of the observation within id and a new "instruction" that tell R that depending of the position of the mydata$dstart1, the value need to be copied in a different column. But then again, I don't know how to do it.

```
     id    dstart1   offence  cod_offence   offence2   offence3  offence4
   1   1   2006-11-25       a          25       NA        NA       NA
   2   1   2006-12-13       b          26       c         NA       NA
   3   1   2006-12-13       c          27       NA        NA       NA
   4   2   2006-02-07       b          26       d         NA       NA
   5   2   2006-02-07       d          28       NA        NA       NA
   6   2   2006-04-12       b          26       d         c        a
   7   2   2006-04-12       d          28       NA        NA       NA
   8   2   2006-04-12       c          27       NA        NA       NA
   9   2   2006-04-12       a          25       NA        NA       NA
```

Thanks again!!!

Comment: Hi, yes, they do work! but I think my problem remains because I asked an incomplete question, can you have a look at it again, please? Thanks!

Comment: @bmora, I just edited my answer to adapt it to your update. Tell me if it's ok for you now

Comment: @bmora I also edited the answer using your new dataset.  Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `base R`

```
indx <- with(mydata, ave(as.numeric(dstart1), id,
           FUN=function(x) c(x[-1]==x[-length(x)], FALSE)))

 transform(mydata, offence2=ifelse(!!indx, 
            c(as.character(offence[-1]), NA), NA))
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
      group_by(id) %>% 
      mutate(offence2= dstart1==lead(dstart1), 
       offence2= ifelse(!is.na(offence2)&offence2,
         as.character(lead(offence)), NA_character_))
#     id    dstart1 offence cod_offence offence2
#1   1 2006-11-25       a          25       NA
#2   1 2006-12-13       b          26        c
#3   1 2006-12-13       c          27       NA
#4   2 2006-02-07       b          26        d
#5   2 2006-02-07       d          28       NA
#6   3 2006-01-15       a          25       NA
#7   3 2006-03-22       a          25       NA
#8   3 2006-09-18       e          29       NA
#9   4 2006-03-04       b          26        a
#10  4 2006-03-04       a          25       NA
#11  4 2006-08-22       c          27        a
#12  4 2006-08-22       a          25       NA
#13  5 2006-04-11       a          25        b
#14  5 2006-04-11       b          26       NA
#15  5 2006-10-19       a          25       NA
```

or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[, indx:=c(dstart1[-1]==dstart1[-.N], FALSE), by=id][,
      offence2:=ifelse(indx, as.character(offence)[which(indx)+1],
                                 NA_character_), by=id][,indx:=NULL]

mydata
 #    id    dstart1 offence cod_offence offence2
 #1:  1 2006-11-25       a          25       NA
 #2:  1 2006-12-13       b          26        c
 #3:  1 2006-12-13       c          27       NA
 #4:  2 2006-02-07       b          26        d
 #5:  2 2006-02-07       d          28       NA
 #6:  3 2006-01-15       a          25       NA
 #7:  3 2006-03-22       a          25       NA
 #8:  3 2006-09-18       e          29       NA
 #9:  4 2006-03-04       b          26        a
#10:  4 2006-03-04       a          25       NA
#11:  4 2006-08-22       c          27        a
#12:  4 2006-08-22       a          25       NA
#13:  5 2006-04-11       a          25        b
#14:  5 2006-04-11       b          26       NA
#15:  5 2006-10-19       a          25       NA
```

#### Update

Using the new dataset `mydata2` and if you use the first method, we get `d1`

```
 indx <- with(mydata2, ave(as.numeric(dstart1), id,
       FUN=function(x) c(x[-1]==x[-length(x)], FALSE)))

 d1 <-  transform(mydata2, offence2=ifelse(!!indx, 
                  c(as.character(offence[-1]), NA), NA))
```

From `d1`, we can create an `indx` column and then use `dcast` to convert from `long` form to `wide` for the column `offence2`.  If there are columns with all `NAs`, we can remove that by using `colSums(is.na(`.  Rename the columns, and then use `mutate_each` from `dplyr` to sort the columns, and finally `cbind` it with `mydata2`

```
 d1$indx <- with(d1, ave(seq_along(id), id, dstart1, FUN=seq_along))
 library(reshape2)

 d2 <- dcast(d1, id + dstart1+indx~indx, value.var='offence2')
 d2New <- d2[,colSums(is.na(d2))!=nrow(d2)]
 nm1 <-  grep("^\\d",colnames(d2New))
 colnames(d2New)[nm1] <- paste0('offence', 2:(length(nm1)+1)) 
 d3 <- d2New[,-3] %>%
                group_by(id, dstart1) %>%
                mutate_each(funs(.[order(.)])) %>%
                ungroup()

 cbind(mydata,d3[,-c(1:2)])
 #    id    dstart1 offence cod_offence offence2 offence3 offence4
 #1  1 2006-11-25       a          25     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
 #2  1 2006-12-13       b          26        c     <NA>     <NA>
 #3  1 2006-12-13       c          27     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
 #4  2 2006-02-07       b          26        d     <NA>     <NA>
 #5  2 2006-02-07       d          28     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
 #6  2 2006-04-12       b          26        d        c        a
 #7  2 2006-04-12       d          28     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
 #8  2 2006-04-12       c          27     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
 #9  2 2006-04-12       a          25     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
```

#### data

```
mydata <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
5, 5), dstart1 = structure(c(13477, 13495, 13495, 13186, 13186, 
13163, 13229, 13409, 13211, 13211, 13382, 13382, 13249, 13249, 
13440), class = "Date"), offence = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor"), cod_offence = c(25, 26, 
27, 26, 28, 25, 25, 29, 26, 25, 27, 25, 25, 26, 25)), .Names = c("id", 
"dstart1", "offence", "cod_offence"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), 
class = "data.frame")

mydata2 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
dstart1 = structure(c(13477, 13495, 13495, 13186, 13186, 13250, 13250,
 13250, 13250), class = "Date"), offence = c("a", "b", "c", "b", "d", "b",
"d", "c", "a"), cod_offence = c(25L, 26L, 27L, 26L, 28L, 26L, 28L, 27L, 25L
)), .Names = c("id", "dstart1", "offence", "cod_offence"), row.names =
 c("1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works!! It's a shame I cant accept more than one answer. Thanks you very much for give me differents alternatives. I've just updated my questions, since I didn't cover all the options in my first question. Thanks again!!

Comment: Wow!! thank you very much. This works perfect with my data!! I still don't understand everything you did, but it works!! I really appreciate your help. I'm learning a lot thanks to you and the people on this site.

Comment: ups! I didn't know I did it... I don't even know when this happened; anyway it wasn't intentionally I'll change it again.

Answer (score 2):

With `split`and a loop :

```
# data with repeated dates /offences
id<-c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5)
dstart<-c("25/11/2006", "13/12/2006","13/12/2006","07/02/2006","07/02/2006",
     "15/01/2006", "22/03/2006","18/09/2006", "04/03/2006","04/03/2006",
     "22/08/2006","22/08/2006","11/04/2006", "11/04/2006", "19/10/2006","19/10/2006","19/10/2006","19/10/2006") 
dstart1<-as.Date(dstart, "%d/%m/%Y")
offence<-c("a","b","c","b","d","a","a","e","b","a","c","a","a","b","a","c","b","a")
cod_offence<-c(25, 26,27,26,28,25,25,29,26,25,27,25,25,26,25,27,25,25)
mydata<-data.frame(id, dstart1, offence, cod_offence)

# see the max offences there are for same id and date
maxoff<-max(table(mydata$id,mydata$dstart1))
mydata[,paste("offence",2:maxoff,sep="")]<-NA

# split your data according to id
splitmydata<-split(mydata,mydata$id) 

# for each "per id dataset", apply a function that looks for repeated offences / dates and fill the "offences" variables in the row with first occurence of specific date.
splitmydata2<-lapply(splitmydata, 
                       function(tab){
                          for(datestart in unique(tab[,"dstart1"])){
                            ind_date<-sort(which(tab[,"dstart1"]==datestart))
                            if(length(ind_date[-1])){
                               tab[ind_date[1],grep("^offence",colnames(tab),value=T)[2:(length(ind_date))]]<-as.character(tab[ind_date[-1],"offence"])
                              }
                           }
                          return(tab)
                       }
                     )

mydata2<-unsplit(splitmydata2,mydata$id) # finally, unsplit your data

> mydata2
   id    dstart1 offence cod_offence offence2 offence3 offence4
1   1 2006-11-25       a          25     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
2   1 2006-12-13       b          26        c     <NA>     <NA>
3   1 2006-12-13       c          27     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
4   2 2006-02-07       b          26        d     <NA>     <NA>
5   2 2006-02-07       d          28     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
6   3 2006-01-15       a          25     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
7   3 2006-03-22       a          25     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
8   3 2006-09-18       e          29     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
9   4 2006-03-04       b          26        a     <NA>     <NA>
10  4 2006-03-04       a          25     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
11  4 2006-08-22       c          27        a     <NA>     <NA>
12  4 2006-08-22       a          25     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
13  5 2006-04-11       a          25        b     <NA>     <NA>
14  5 2006-04-11       b          26     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
15  5 2006-10-19       a          25        c        b        a
16  5 2006-10-19       c          27     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
17  5 2006-10-19       b          25     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
18  5 2006-10-19       a          25     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
```

Comment: @akrun, "better solutions" is kind of subjective... Your solution(s)  may be better in terms of efficiency but mine is probably closer to what the OP had in mind...

Comment: @CathG Okay, no problem.  I just got curious, that is all.

Comment: @akrun I don't know, it is one of the terminology used by the OP.

Comment: I accepted @CathG solution because I thought it would work with a more complex structure, but it wasn't because of my mistake!
All the solution worked very well, but I asked an incomplete question, so my problem is still there. I updated the question if you can have a look at it. Thanks again

Comment: @CathG Sorry again!! I meant repeated date within individual, with different offences

Comment: Thank you very much, I really like your solution because it looks simpler and pretty, but it didn't work with my data. A warning message appeared after the split(mydata,id) command: "In split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable" I read that this is only a warning, so I tried to run the rest of the code, but the debug windows appeared, so  it didn't work :(
I really appreciate your help, I'll try to see where the problem is... I'm learning a lot with your help.

Comment: @bmora, I fixed the bug : the warning was because I used `id` variable instead of `mydata$id` in the `split`/`unsplit` instructions. (So if `mydata$id` and `id` are not the same, it cannot work). Sorry for that ! It should work now. Please, if you don't mind, let me know if it solves the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, I couldn't check this yesterday. Thanks for solving this, now it works perfectly. I spotted the same problem, but since it did work with the example I thought the problem was different. Thanks again for helping me so much!! best!

Comment: @bmora, ok great, thanks for the answer and don't worry for the delay. I'm happy it works now ! Too bad I edited my answer with a tiny bug, made me loose your acceptation... :-(