# Copy values from one row to another based on condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I have this dataset:

```
# Data
movmnt_id <- c("101", "601", "105", "321")
plant <- c("FF", "FF", "DO", "BO")
loc <- c("MM", "MM", "KB", "RD")
vendor <- c(123, NA,NA,NA)
customer <- c(456, NA,NA,NA)
check <- c(NA, NA, "defined", "defined")

df <-  data.frame(movmnt_id, plant, loc, vendor,customer,check)

  movmnt_id plant loc vendor customer   check
1       101    FF  MM    123      456    <NA>
2       601    FF  MM     NA       NA    <NA>
3       105    DO  KB     NA       NA defined
4       321    BO  RD     NA       NA defined
```

I need to get this output (in the second row `vendor` & `customer` are copied from the first row):

```
  movmnt_id plant loc vendor customer   check
1       101    FF  MM    123      456    <NA>
2       601    FF  MM    123      456    <NA>
3       105    DO  KB     NA       NA defined
4       321    BO  RD     NA       NA defined
```

The condition is following:

```
If in current row `movmnt_id `== 601 
 -> take row *WHERE* `plant` & `loc` are the same as in the current row
              *AND* `movmnt_id  == 101`
              *AND* is.na(check)
 -> copy from found row `vendor` & `customer` to the current row
```

I could think about some for loop, but for my dataset it will be too heavy.
I am wondering if there is more elegant solution with less computational cost.

I was trying to adapt solutions from these cases, but did not succeed:

- [How to populate values of one row conditional of another row in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096447/how-to-populate-values-of-one-row-conditional-of-another-row-in-r)
- [copy values of a column into another column based on a condition using a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126609/copy-values-of-a-column-into-another-column-based-on-a-condition-using-a-loop)
- [r - copy value based on match in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998856/r-copy-value-based-on-match-in-another-column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To implement your conditions you can try the following -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(plant, loc) %>%
  mutate(across(c(vendor, customer), 
              ~ifelse(movmnt_id == '601' & is.na(.), 
                      .[is.na(check) & movmnt_id == 101], .))) %>%
  ungroup

#  movmnt_id plant loc   vendor customer check  
#  <chr>     <chr> <chr>  <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>  
#1 101       FF    MM       123      456 NA     
#2 601       FF    MM       123      456 NA     
#3 105       DO    KB        NA       NA defined
#4 321       BO    RD        NA       NA defined
```

Comment: Thank you, @Ronak! It works. Could you, please explain what means this part of condition  `& is.na(.)`?  I have tried without it and it works.

Comment: It checks if the current value that we are replacing is `NA`. If the second row in `vendor` would not have been `NA` it would not replace the value. Try this with `df$vendor[2] <- 1`

Comment: Dear Ronak Shah, may I ask if you have any idea why I could get the result but the OP could not? Could have anything to do with the version of `dplyr`?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR I think OP might be using `data.table::first` (which gives error) and not `dplyr::first` (which does not give error). Although it might not be what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This solution may help but I assumed that these two values are copied in the second row since they share the same value for `loc` & `plant` columns:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(plant, loc) %>%
  mutate(across(vendor:customer, ~ first(na.omit(.x))))

  movmnt_id plant loc   vendor customer check  
  <chr>     <chr> <chr>  <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>  
1 101       FF    MM       123      456 NA     
2 601       FF    MM       123      456 NA     
3 105       DO    KB        NA       NA defined
4 321       BO    RD        NA       NA defined
```

Comment: Hi Anoushiravan, I dont know why I have this error, when I try your solution:
 `Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` can't be recycled to size 1.
ℹ Input `..1` is `across(vendor:customer, ~first(na.omit(.x)))`.
ℹ Input `..1` must be size 1, not 0.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: plant = "BO", loc = "RD".`

Comment: Hi, oh I'm sorry. I thought that might be the case in a larger data set, because I generalized it to all grouping variables. But I think you only meant this replacement to be made for this particular row id `601`.

Comment: But it worked for me on the small dataset. May I ask what is your version of `dplyr`. I checked it again with the data set you presented above and it worked!

Comment: Yes, It is strange that it is not working for me. dplyr version = ‘1.0.2’

Comment: I used to have these sorts of conflicts and I guess it has something to do with the version. Mine is `1.0.5` . I recommend you update yours and I believe it will work then.

Comment: I have another packages which are conflicting with dplyr and when I run your code nothing changes, so I am adding `dplyr::` before mutate. But I am doing it for all cases with dplyr

Comment: There have been some occasions that I had produced the desired output and the OP could not, but after they updated their packages, the problem solved.

Comment: Ok, I will try with updated package. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. If it worked just please let me know.